# Sort alphabetically several names via "Bubble Sort" with the notes also

Tags: java

I have 2 arrays with several names and notes

```
String[] tabString = {"Erika", "Amelia", "Celine"};
int[] tabInt = {4,5,8};
```

I have to sort alphabetically for example

```
"Amelia" => 5
"Celine" => 8 
"Erika" =>  4
```

However, I have to use a `bubbleSort` method ! The `sort()` function is not allowed for this exercise.

Here is my method (I don't know if it's correct ?)

```
public static void bubbleSort(String[] stringArray) {
        int n = stringArray.length;
        String temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                if (stringArray[j - 1].compareTo( stringArray[j] ) > 0) {
                    temp = stringArray[j - 1]; 
                    stringArray[j - 1] = stringArray[j];
                    stringArray[j] = temp; 
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I am stuck to display, How should I retrieve my 2 arrays? I have to do 2 loops ?

```
public static void display(String[] tabString, int[] tabInt){
    for(int i=0; i<tabString.length; i++){
      System.out.print(tabString[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your result sorted alphabetically? A -> E -> C?

Comment: if both `tabString` and `tabInt` are ordered, you can just use the counter `i` for both. `System.out.println(tabString[i] + " =>" + String.valueOf(tabInt[i]))`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you just asking if you would use two loops to iterate over two different arrays?  Generally, yes.  Did you try?  Did something not work as expected?

Comment: @Wesley De Keirsmaeke: Sorry! I have edtied ! :-)

Comment: @David: After the creation of my `bulleSort` method. How to display this?

Comment: In your bubblesort method, you are only sorting one array. But I assume the second array should be rearranged to match the changes on the first one, right? How do you expect to know what the new positions in the second one should be?

Comment: @joel: Is `System.out.print(tabString[i] + " ")` not outputting displaying anything when you run it?

Comment: @Pablo: Thank you but I am stuck with the parameters.. `public static void display(String[] tab, int[] tab2){
    for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
      System.out.println(tabString[i] + " =>" + String.valueOf(tabInt[i]))
    }
  }`

Comment: @joel why do you now call them `tab` and `tab2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to sync the sorting of the names with the array of integers.

I assume both arrays have the same length, such that there is an int for every name.

Provided the above, you can sort both arrays to the method bubbleSort, create 2 temp values, tempString and tempInt and sort the Int in accordance with your sorting of the Strings:

```
   public static void bubbleSort(String[] stringArray, Int[] intArray) {
        int n = stringArray.length;
        String tempString;
        Int tempInt
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                if (stringArray[j - 1].compareTo( stringArray[j] ) > 0) {
                    tempString = stringArray[j - 1]; 
                    tempInt = intArray[j - 1]
                    stringArray[j - 1] = stringArray[j];
                    intArray[j - 1] = intArray[j]
                    stringArray[j] = tempString; 
                    intArray[j] = tempInt
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when you want to print it

```
public static void display(String[] tabString, int[] tabInt){
    for(int i=0; i<tabString.length; i++){
      System.out.print(tabString[i] + " " + tabInt[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This is "the simplest" solution I could think of, if you are limited by your assignment. If not, consider using a [TreeMap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treemap-in-java/), [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or other sorted  [map](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map)

I hope this answered your question

Answer (score 1):

It is always safe to create an array of `your own custom class` and then apply sorting.

**This ensures clean code and reduces chances for errors.**

Have a look at the following code, where `tabString` and `tabInt` are part of class `Pair` and sorting is applied on basis of `tabString`:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

//Our custom class to hold tabString and tabInt
class Pair { 
    String tabString; 
    int tabInt; 

    // Constructor 
    public Pair(String tabString, int tabInt) 
    { 
        this.tabString = tabString; 
        this.tabInt = tabInt; 
    } 
}

public class Solution{


    static void bubbleSort(Pair[] arr) {
        int n = arr.length;
        String temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1].tabString.compareTo( arr[j].tabString ) > 0) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1].tabString; 
                    arr[j - 1].tabString = arr[j].tabString;
                    arr[j].tabString = temp; 
                }

            }
        }
    }

    static void printArray(Pair arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            System.out.println(arr[i].tabString + " " + arr[i].tabInt);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] tabString = {"Erika", "Amelia", "Celine"};
        int[] tabInt = {4,5,8};

        int N = tabString.length;

        Pair arr[] = new Pair[N];

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            arr[i] = new Pair(tabString[i], tabInt[i]);
        }

        bubbleSort(arr);
        printArray(arr);
    }

}
```